# How to get object with User username?

Tags: python, django

From the url I get the username. Now with a help of a username a I also want to get exact User object. Here is my code:

```
author = UserProfile.objects.get(user.username_iexact = username)
```

However, I get a error: `keyword can't be an expression`

How to make it work?

Comment: if you get your answer mark it as verified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

`author = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact='your_username')`.

Read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify as follow ([use double underscore](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) instead of dot):

```
author = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=username)
```